# Full effects from Poisson GLM

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-linear-model

I am running a Poisson GLM with count data as response variable and both continuous and categorical variables as predictors. I made use of the following (dispersion is OK):

```
model.glm = glm(response ~ x1 + x2 + x3+..., family="poisson", data=mydata)
summary(model.glm)
```

By exploring the loadings, I found out that the results do not show the full effects of the variables, leaving out some levels in the categorical variables. What brought me here to ask whether there is any way to get the full effects of my variables (including levels of categorical variables even if not significant).

Comment: If you have a $k$-level categorical variable, you should loose only 1 of these. Google "dummy variable trap" to learn why. It's not a matter of statistical significance. Occasionally, you might loose others if your cells are getting thin.

Answer (score 1):

When you fit a model in R with a categorical response R will absorb one of the levels into the intercept. To determine what is being absorbed into the intercept (what R baselines at) you can do,

```
levels(factor(variable))
```

the one that R lists first will be the level that is absorbed into the intercept. The coefficients for the other levels will be adjustments to the intercept. To not have R baseline and to give you the means for each level you can do,

```
model.glm = glm(response ~ 0+ x1 + x2 + x3+..., family="poisson", data=mydata)
```

which will not fit an intercept term.

Comment: Thanks Lauren, but I think model.glm = glm(response ~ 0+ x1 + x2 + x3+..., family="poisson", data=mydata) gives only insights for the first variable of the formula.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by, "gives only insights for the first variable of the formula.".